# What is meaning of "Observability of a Package" in Chapter 7 Of JLS

Tags: java, jls

I am learning Java Language Specification, and I have a problem about the meaning of `"Observability of a Package"` in [JLS §7.4.3 - Observability of a Package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4.3):

> A package is observable if and only if either:
>
> - A compilation unit containing a declaration of the package is observable (§7.3).
> - A subpackage of the package is observable.

My questions are

1. How to understand the observability of packages
2. How to understand the second condition `A subpackage of the package is observable`

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/198137/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/Observable-packages

Comment: I had already read this topic before, but it can't persuade me, and the topic is posted "2001-3-8 10:23pm".

Answer (score 3):

There are four concepts in JLS which it would be nice to precise:

1) A Compilation unit is observable
2) A Compilation unit is always observable
3) A Package is observable
4) A Package is always observable

1) Lets assume that Compilation unit "A" is observable.
This means that Java compiler can somehow find this Compilation unit and parse/compile its content.

2) A Compilation unit is always observable if any compilation process independently of its properties can find and parse/compile this compilation unit.
Usually Compilation units which are always observable are provided by Java implementors.

3) A package is observable if and only if there exist at least one compilation unit of this package that is observable
or there exist at least one subpackage that is observable.
Also I want to note that package still can contain compilation units or subpackages which are not observable.

4) A package is always observable if and only if there exist at least one compilation unit of this package that is always observable
or there exist at least one subpackage that is always observable.
Usually subpackages which are always observable are provided by Java implementors.
Also I want to note that package still can contain compilation units or subpackages which are not observable.

Answer (score 1):

This is the continuation of my previous answer.

Let's consider how the four above concepts related to the implementation of "Java SE 8" from Oracle.

First of all Compilation Units are simple files and packages are folders of local file system.

1) How we make particular compilation Unit observable in particular compliation?
For this purpose we use Java Compiler javac and enumerate Compilation Inits separating them with spaces.

For example, if current folder is D:\Foo1\Foo2 and we write

javac com\myclass1\MyClass1.java com\myclass2\MyClass2.java

we compile two compilation inits:
D:\Foo1\Foo2\com\myclass1\MyClass1.java
D:\Foo1\Foo2\com\myclass2\MyClass2.java

Also we can modify our compilation with the following options:
1) "-sourcepath" option of javac compiler.
2) "-classpath" or "-cp" options of javac compiler.
3) "CLASSPATH" environment variable.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html
for more details.

Also I want to note that "-sourcepath" searches only for Compilation Units but "-classpath" (or -cp" and "CLASSPATH") can search not only Compilation Units but also Compiled Java classes (*.class files) which optionally can be bundled in jar/zip files.
This compiled classes are not Compilation Units now but they were compilation units before their compilation.
And we can consider them as "modified" compilation units or Compilation Units under which some process was previously performed.
Hence by means of the three options above we can add more Compilation Units to our particular compilation.

2) Always Observable compilation Units are bundled with the installation of "Java SE 8" and located in "...\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib".
   Most of them are placed in well known "rt.jar". But compilation units placed in other jars are also always observable.
   As you can see they are bundled as compiled class-files located in jar files and hence they are "modified" compilation units.

3) If you look through "...\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib" you will find quite many always observable packages:

java       - always observable according to the spec

java.lang  - always observable according to the spec

java.io    - always observable according to the spec

java.applet

java.awt

java.beans

java.math

java.net

java.nio

java.rmi

java.security

java.sql

java.text

java.time

java.util

.........

Also you can place your own libs into "...\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\ext" in order to you libs were always observable.